# Trying to add 1 to a Split String

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify a retrieved date `ex: 2013-01-20 00:59:06` by adding `+1` to the day if the time is less than 20:00. The reason is that if the time retrieved is less than 20:00, it means that it must be then somewhere between 00:00 and 07:00 - meaning it's the next day.

Here is what I did:

```
var WhenDateUnformatted = $('#when').val().split('/');
var startTimeSPLIT = startTime.split(':');

if (WhenDateUnformatted[1] < 20) {
var WhenDateUnformatted[1] = WhenDateUnformatted[1] + 1;
}

var WhenDate = WhenDateUnformatted[2] + '-' + WhenDateUnformatted[0] + '-' + WhenDateUnformatted[1] + ' ' + startTime + ':00';
```

The error I receive is:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>
> var WhenDateUnformatted[1] = WhenDateUnformatted[1] + 1;

It doesn't like the `[1]`

Does that mean I have to convert `WhenDateUnformatted[1]` to an individual variable first if I want to do anything with it?

Thanks! :)

**Edit:** I made a mistake, the first part should be

```
if (startTimeSPLIT[0] < 20) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are re-declaring WhenDateUnformatted.  Just assign it a value inside your if statement.

```
var WhenDateUnformatted = $('#when').val().split('/');
var startTimeSPLIT = startTime.split(':');

var parsedWhenDateUnformatted = parseInt(WhenDateUnformatted[1],10);
if (parsedWhenDateUnformatted < 20) {
    WhenDateUnformatted[1] = (parsedWhenDateUnformatted + 1).toString();
}
```

In response to your comment and to update in accordance with Robrich's input, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

WhenDateUnformatted[1] is a string, not a number.  Adding 1 to it does weird things.  Try `parseInt(WhenDateUnformatted[1],10)` to make it a number first.

Comment: Thanks! Do I declare that before the `if`?

Comment: Putting it inside the `if` like this `parseInt(WhenDateUnformatted[1],10) = WhenDateUnformatted[1] + 1;` causes this error: `ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side`

Comment: Yes, and probably also declare a new var with this value -- probably easier than comparing the array entry each time.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a local variable WhenDateUnformatted inside your loop by using the var keyword, in the line

`var WhenDateUnformatted[1] = WhenDateUnformatted[1] + 1;`

That can't be what you are trying to do... once outside the loop your value will be unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is bad
var arr = [] /* or whatever*/;
var arr[1] = arr[1] + 1;

// This is good
var arr = [] /* or whatever*/;
arr[1] = arr[1] + 1; /* Or simply: arr[1]++; */
```

**[Mastering Javascript Arrays](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX1)**